# Prevent form from being submitted - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I want to check if there's at least one checkbox that checked in a form after the submit button is clicked, if no, the the user should get message and the form SHOULDN'T be submit, so I wrote this code:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#price_quote_create_invoice').click(function () {
       $('.price-quotes-table input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
           if ( $(this).is(':checked') ){
                $('#post').submit();
                return false;
           } else {
               alert("You didn't chose any checkbox!");
               return false;
           }
       }) ;
    });
});
```

However, after I press ok on the alert box, the form does submit.

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost right.

You return false on a click event but what you really want to do is to stop the submit event.

Change like this.

```
$('#yourFormId').submit(function(){
  if (!$(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length) {
   alert("You didn't chose any checkbox!");
   return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: So. Submit form -> Prevent submitting (`e.preventDefault();`) -> Check if chekked or not and show alert. You do realise that the form will never be send now, right?

Comment: Yep you're right. I just coded those lines too quickly. My bad. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 alert('You didn't chose any checkbox!');
```

You have an additional comma in your alert..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `event.preventDefault()` to do this. `event` is the first argument of your `click` function. [Reference](https://api.jquery.com/click/)